# Error sintaxis con case en mysql utilizando SP

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Bueno desde phpMyAdmin estoy realizando un crud con case, y bueno me dice que hay error de sintaxis nada más que no le veo algo malo.

Mi código es este:

```
create PROCEDURE usuarioXY
(in _idUser int(11),
in _usuario char(50),
in _consetrasena char(50),
in accion varchar(40)
)
begin 
    case accion
     when 'nuevo' then 
        insert into usuarios (usuario, contrasena) values (_usuario, _contrasena);
     when 'editar' then 
        update usuarios set 
        usuario = _usuario, contrasena = _contrasena;
     when 'eliminar' then 
        delete from usuarios where idUser = _idUser;
     when 'consulta' then 
        select * from usuarios where idUser = _idUser;
     end case 
end
```

El error que me sale es este:

> ## 1064 - Algo está equivocado en su sintax cerca ' ' en la linea 10

la cual es después del case, es en la línea del insert:

```
when 'nuevo' then 
    insert into usuarios (usuario, contrasena) values (_usuario, _contrasena);
```

¿alguien me podría decir que puede estar pasando?
no logro ver el error.

Answer (score 1):

La instrucción CASE no controla el flujo de ejecución de instrucciones, para ello tienes la instrucción condicional IF: [IF Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html)

En lo personal, yo no le veo ventaja alguna a los procedimientos "multi-uso", "estorban" a la legibilidad, al mantenimiento y sobre todo no son predecibles para sostener un plan de ejecución. Puedes optar por funciones de tipo UPSERT, por ejemplo: [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE Syntax](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html)